# Flip view question

Tags: iphone, sdk

I'm new with the Apple SDK and I've got a question about a flip view ... I have the following structure

[main]

-[tapbar]

-- [View 1]

--- [Scrollview]

---- [View 1.1]

---- [View 1.2]

---- [View 1.3]

-- [View 2]

-- [View 3]

The subviews in [scrollview] have a button that will show a new view but flipped. 
I used the template example that was in the SDK. But now when I click the button, the view (for example [View 1.1]) will flip. 
But I want the while screen to flip, so I need to flip (I think) the tabbar..

Is there a way to reach [main] from [View 1.1] so I can flip the tabbar with the new view?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd rather use a [Modal View](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) with a flip animation. This should flip the whole screen.

Comment: ah thnx ... I will try it tonight

Answer (score 0):

I've got it ... I used the AppDelegate to get to the root tabbar and flip it.